# How does aggression transferring work neurologically?

Tags: neuroscience, emotion, aggression

Psychologist often prefict phenomena before they are scientifically observed. For example they have known for a long time that if you don't think about something for some time, you forget it. This can be explained as the loss of the connection between neurons when no signal goes through them.

How could we explain the transferring aggression similarly?